# Looking for the name of an 80s anime movie involving a spaceship of girls fighting aliens

Tags: gall-force

I saw a great anime movie on TV when I was young, but I don't remember its title.

I suppose it is an anime movie from the early 80s.

The movie opens with a space battle with a lot of fighters and a spaceship whose crew consisted of only girls.

I think one of them is called Ruby. When the battle ends, an alien life form enters the spaceship. In an attempt to kill this intruder, one of the girls dies and the rest of the crew eject her body into outer space.

Later, for some reason, the spaceship starts to become unstable and everyone must evacuate the spaceship using a smaller emergency ship.

The controls for the release mechanism for the emergency ship does not work. One of the girls, who is revealed to be a robot, sacrifices herself in order to release the ship. The spaceship then explodes. All the survivors then land on a nearby planet.

One of the passengers on the ship is a baby which has the ability to grow supernaturally fast.

After a while, the alien enemy locates the planet and starts the attack. The movie concludes, when the baby, now a fully grown woman, does something in the ship that causes all the aliens to die in a huge wave explosion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [this link from AVClub](http://avclub.com/articles/ask-the-av-club-march-7-2008,2197), I think it could be [Gall Force: Eternal Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall_Force#First_Story_Arc).